# Data hasn't saved thorough phpmyadmin

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to save a form data through codeigniter framework in PhPMyadmin.But it's not working. it redirected to my form page automatically.

here is my View (form page's) code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Forms</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Basic Form Elements
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <form action"<?php echo base_url();?>super_admin/save_category" method="post" >
                                     <div>

                                        <?php 
                                        $message=$this->session->userdata('message');
                                        if($message){
                                            echo $message;
                                            $this->session->unset_userdata('message');
                                        }
                                        ?>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Text Input</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="category_name">
                                        <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Text area</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" name="category_description" rows="3"></textarea>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Radio Buttons</label>
                                        <div class="radio">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="radio" name="publication_status"   id="optionsRadios1" value="1" checked>Published
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="radio">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="radio" name="publication_status" id="optionsRadios2" value="0">Unpublished
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit </button>
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset </button>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
```

And here is my Controller code :

```
<?php
//session_start();
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
*  
*/
class Super_Admin extends CI_Controller
{ 
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $admin_id=$this->session->userdata('admin_id');
        if($admin_id==NULL){
            redirect('admin_login','refresh');
        }
    }
    public function index()
        {

            $this->load->view('admin/admin_master');
        }
        public function add_category(){
            $data=array();
            //$data['admin_content']=$this->load->view('admin/add_category','',TRUE);
            $data['title']='Add category';
            $this->load->view('admin/add_category',$data);
        }
        public function save_category(){
            $data=array();
            $data['category_name']=$this->input->post('category_name',TRUE);
            $data['category_description']=$this->input->post('category_description',TRUE);
            $data['publication_status']=$this->input->post('publication_status',TRUE);
            $this->super_admin_model->save_category_info($data);
            $sdata=array();
            $sdata['message']="Save Category information successfully";
            $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);
            redirect('super_admin/add_category');
        }

    public function logout(){
        $this->session->unset_userdata('admin_name');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('admin_id');
        $sdata=array();
        $sdata['message']='You are successfully logout!';
        $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);
        redirect('admin_login','refresh');
    }
}


?>
```

And here is my Model code :

```
<?php

class Super_Admin_Model extends CI_Model{
    public function save_category_info($data){
        $this->db->insert('tbl_category',$data);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your controller should only have first letter upper case on file and class name. Same with your models.

Comment: i don't understand what you have said. I have put all the class name in capital letter even for the model. That's not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to load your model.

```
public function save_category(){
            $this->load->model('super_Admin_Model', 'model'); //May be you forget this.

            $data= array(
                    'category_name' => $this->input->post('category_name',TRUE),
                    'category_description' => $this->input->post('category_description',TRUE),
                    'publication_status' => $this->input->post('publication_status',TRUE)
                   );

            $this->model->save_category_info($data);

            $sdata=array();
            $sdata['message']="Save Category information successfully";
            $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);
            redirect('super_admin/add_category');
        }
```

Comment: i put my model in "autoload.php" .

Comment: Please check the case of model name. I mean `super_Admin_Model` not `super_admin_model`.